# Formula to generate "Score" that ranges between 0 and 100 based on many inputs

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

Suppose you have a set of data looking like this:

```
views: 1500
likes: 23
avgRating: 7
ratings: 2
purchases: 6
```

Note, that those numbers may vary dramatically. Now I want to create a formula, that outputs a "score" between 0 and 100 based on the given data. I also want set different "weights" for every variable, to give them an "importance factor".

P.S.: The purpose is to create a ranking system which sorts based on the score.

Comment: This is too vague.  We have no idea how you are weighing the various components relative to one another....how many views offsets a one point loss in ratings, say?  This is a purely subjective matter, not a mathematical one.

Comment: So your problem is?

Comment: You might want to sort the observations and use *percentile* rankings.

Comment: I'd recommend the book *Who's #1?  The Science of Rating and Ranking* by Amy N. Langville and Carl D. Meyer, Princeton Univ. Press, 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there is no end to the number of ways this might be done. Here is
one idea to get you started thinking. I know almost nothing about your business and your objectives, so I suppose you will want to modify my suggestions.

**Put each measure on a scale of 0 to 100.** Start by putting each type of data on a scale between o and 100, where
0 is safely below the smallest value and 100 safely above the largest.

For example, maybe your data on 10,000 `views` has numbers that run from
150 to 3819.  You know `views` can't be less than 0 and suppose it will stay
below 5000. Then your score for `views` could be the number of views divided by 50.

```
summary(views)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    150    1659    1996    1994    2330    3819
```

If you absolutely can't imagine a top value from your data, maybe take the square root
of the log of `views` and see if you can guess a top value of the modified
data.

```
summary(sqrt(views))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  12.25   40.73   44.68   44.29   48.27   61.80
```

Maybe you could use 100 as the max, and `sqrt(views)` as the score.

```
summary(log(views))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  5.011   7.414   7.599   7.563   7.754   8.248
```

Maybe you could use 10 as the max and multiply `log(views)` by 10 to get a score.

But use transformations with care. If you use transformations you might change symmetrical data into
skewed data (as here). If you start with right-skewed data, then transformations might make scores more nearly symmetrical. Look at some plots to see the effects of any transformations.

[image]

Moving along, maybe you know `avgRating` *has* to be between 0 and 10, so the score for that could
be found by multiplying by 10.

In this way you will get five scores $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_5.$  Over time, you
may find you have to change some of these because traffic is becoming much
heavier or much sparser.

**Decide on weights that add to 1:** Then decide how important each of these measures is. You have five of them.
Weights $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_5$ should be positive fractions adding to $1$:
perhaps something like .1, .25, .25, .1, .3.

**Find total score:** Then the total score for each item would be 
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^5 w_is_i = w_1s_1 + w_2s_2 + \cdots + w_5s_5,$$ which
will lie between 0 and 100.

Comment: If you can actually use something like this, then I suggest you edit your question so it will be clear to a wider class of viewers. That might result in even better suggestions. // @hardmath's idea has merit, but it uses the full range of scores from near 0 to near 100 (details depending on the operative def'n of percentile), leaving no room for future lower or higher scores. Maybe (for my 1st step) use percentile rank multiplied by 0.8 and add 10? Gives scale from 10 to 90. //Toward the goal of more input, I've nominated your Q for reopening.